# Does dividing the windows in half (code and output) help visualization?

Tags: coding-style

For instance, if you are coding a website, does it help if you keep the browser visible in the upper half of the screen?

Or you think that seen the code at full screen makes things more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you don't shrink your source code view too much, it surely helps to have your output visible.

Even double monitors are not too much to that end.